# scrollview not working after back from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I'm facing a strange situation, I have designed a fragment to include a `ScrollView` but when i go to another fragment and back from backstack 
`View` is Converted to another view not `ScrollView` and screen items overlaps

**fragment XML:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.eh.waseldriver.TripDetailsFragment"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/trip_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></include>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_trip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/withoutbackgroundcolor"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="طلب إلغاء الرحله"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recy_decoming_trips"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recy_decoming_trips"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/include"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/include"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/include"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and the below xml code is the another fragment design

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.eh.waseldriver.ReportFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="من فضلك إدخل التفاصيل التى تود الابلاغ عنها"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_report"
    android:layout_width="268dp"
    android:layout_height="123dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_send_report"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:text="إرسال"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Note that `ConstraintLayout` Tag is closed but not appearing on the above

[image]

also you could check this GIF to see what happens it may help in investigating what is the wrong

[GIF Link](https://giphy.com/gifs/3PxR2GIsLsNuZNserg)

I want to know the cause and how to solve it

Comment: It is possible that you have missed to call addToBackstack() when you are adding new fragment. However have a look to this [page](http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2015/08/16/how-to-avoid-fragments-overlapping-due-to-backstack-nightmare-in-android/). Read it carefully, it helped me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I added this line of code  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);